# Shibboleth-Idp setup: Issue with the data-connectors in attribute-resolver.xml

Tags: tomcat6, shibboleth

I have setup the shibboleth-Idp as servelet in servelet container tomcat6. However, tomcat start the servelet fails to load. My data connectors are causing it.

The code I am using for connectors is as follows:

```
<resolver:DataConnector id="myLDAP" xsi:type="dc:LDAPDirectory"
        ldapURL="ldap://ldap.example.org" 
        baseDN="ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" 
        principal="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org"
        principalCredential="khurram">
        <dc:FilterTemplate>
            <![CDATA[
                (uid=$requestContext.principalName)
            ]]>
        </dc:FilterTemplate>
    </resolver:DataConnector>

  <!-- StoredID (persistentID) Connector -->
    <resolver:DataConnector id="myStoredId"
        xsi:type="dc:StoredId"
        generatedAttributeID="persistentID"
        sourceAttributeID="swissEduPersonUniqueID"
        salt="CsAizrOmTV7GR7/wSoHX32s0NbHCi7hppi11kLhk/XFRpqCo">
    <resolver:Dependency ref="swissEduPersonUniqueID" />
        <dc:ApplicationManagedConnection
            jdbcDriver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbcURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shibboleth?autoReconnect=true"
            jdbcUserName="shibboleth"
            jdbcPassword="demo" />
    </resolver:DataConnector>
```

The error I get in shibboeth IDP-Process.log logs is as follows

> 02:01:40.015 - ERROR
>   [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.config.BaseService:188] -
>   Configuration was not loaded for shibboleth.AttributeResolver service,
>   error creating components.  The root cause of this error was:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key
>   'DataConnectorAttributeDefinitionDependencyRef' with value
>   'swissEduPersonUniqueID' not found for identity constraint of element
>   'AttributeResolver'.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Shibboleth does not know about **swissEduPersonUniqueID**. It is missing from you configuration file.